# Opamp output on loaded and unloaded cases

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, analog, bjt, logic-gates

I have a design project to rotate a motor. In order to do that, I have designed a very simple but smart circuit. However, in signal comparison stage, if it is unloaded, i.e. not connected with the next stage of the design, it gives the output as expected. However, if connects two stages, if gives unexpected outputs. I could not express this situation. Design and test results are given as attached.

Could you help me to express what is wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like Q1 needs a base resistor

Comment: Does Value of the resistor matter? Thnx in advance.

Comment: It should be properly sized to limit the base current of the transistor to a reasonable level.

Comment: Q1 no base resistor, Q2 no base connection, no supply to top or bottom of H-bridge,  Q1 and Q2 will be destroyed by the LM358 due to EB avalanche ...complete your circuit before you expect results.

Comment: Your power supply scheme is dubious, at best. The LM78xx regulators (like most regulators) cannot sink current so if the loading from +12 to "GND" is greater than the loading from "GND" to -12 the voltage difference between the latter rails will increase.